# remove all aria-hidden="true" from source code

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to remove all the **aria-hidden="true"** from my html using tampermonkey

I've tried to make them visible using this code

```
   var HiddenElements = document.evaluate("//[@aria-hidden='true']",
       document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
     for (var i = HiddenElements.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       var elmHidden = HiddenElements.snapshotItem(i);
       elmHidden.style.outline = 'rgb(255, 0, 78) dashed 3px';
       elmHidden.ariahidden = 'false';
   }
```

Is there any way to make this work ? and how to debug the results while testing?

Regards!

Comment: Add `*` after `//`.

Comment: thank you! but I guess the last line is wrong,  elmHidden.ariahidden='false'; how to correct it?

Comment: elmHidden.removeAttribute('aria-hidden')

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[aria-hidden="true"]').forEach(item => {

  item.style.outline = 'rgb(255, 0, 78) dashed 3px';
  item.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false'); 

  // or remove it
  item.removeAttribute('aria-hidden');
});
```